# QQ plot with one dataset

Tags: distributions, qq-plot

I have been asked to "construct a (normal) QQ plot" for a set of numbers. However it is not a set of pairs or a pair of sets, just a single set of numbers.

If we go ahead and assume the second probability distribution is the normal distribution, how would I go about satisfying this request?

Comment: What software are you using? Or are you asking how to do the calculations manually?

Comment: I'm interested in doing it manually.

Comment: @oadams: it's pretty difficult to do manually. You have to fit a normal model to the data first, and then figure out the probability of each data point according to that model (or probabilities of quantiles in the data and the model).

Answer (score 3):

In R:

```
## generate some data to represent the set of numbers you do have
set.seed(2)
set1 <- rt(100, df = 2)
## Draw the QQ-Plot
qqnorm(set1)
## Add a reference line
qqline(set1)
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the reference line? If the points form an approximately straight line but that line is quite different from the reference line, how should that be interpreted?

Comment: If the points follow a normal distribution (in this case) they should be roughly along the line showing no systematic variation from that line.

Comment: Do you mean roughly along the line given by `qqline`, or roughly along any straight line? For example, in `set.seed(33); x <- rnorm(40); qqnorm(x); qqline(x)` the points seem to fit a different straight line much better than the `qqline` line. In this example, we know that the data is normally distributed, but how would a plot like this be interpreted if we didn't know that?

Comment: I read that differently. In general the simulated data follows a normal distribution but there is some deviation in the tails of the observed data. Given the small sample size, this is not unexpected. The observed data should roughly follow the reference line; departures from the line indicate departures from the reference distribution. How you interpret that will depend on the data you have to hand.

Comment: @mark999 as stated with?qqline, the line is the one that passes through the first and third quartile, not the ols regression line.

Comment: @Bogdan thanks for your comment. I knew that qqline went through the first and third quartiles, and was asking why this particular line should be used, rather than a different line (such as the ols regression line).

Comment: @mark999: If the data (`y`) is normally distributed, with the same mean and variance as your model, it'll follow `y=x`. If the y has a higher mean, the data will be above the line `y=x`. If it has a higher variance, the slope will be steeper. Try `x <- rnorm(100); y <- rnorm(100, mean=2); qqplot(x=x,y=y); lines(c(-10,10), c(-10,10), col='red')` and `x <- rnorm(100); y <- rnorm(100, sd=2); qqplot(x=x,y=y); lines(c(-10,10), c(-10,10), col='red')`. If you don't care about the mean and sd, but just about the normality, then all that matters is that the data closely approximate a straight line.